# Count occurance of specific words in a text file in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, word-count

I'm trying to count the number of an item in a text file, by counting each instance the item was entered into the file earlier on in the program.

I already have the text read from the file and in a text box. The problem is that my current code was just counting the characters in the textbox and not the number of times my desired word was in the file.

```
For Each desiredword As String In txtContentofFile.Text
        intdesiredword = intdesiredword + 1
        txtdesiredwordcount.Text = intdesiredword
Next
```

This counts the characters in the textbox instead of counting the number of desired words. I tried repeatedly before asking help and searched extensively, but I just don't understand what's wrong with my code. Please help :)

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use Regular Expressions in this type of situation.  They are very tricky to understand but they are extremely powerful and typically faster than other string manipulation techniques.

```
Dim AllMatchResults As MatchCollection
Try
    Dim RegexObj As New Regex(desiredword)
    AllMatchResults = RegexObj.Matches(txtContentofFile.Text)
    If AllMatchResults.Count > 0 Then
        ' Access individual matches using AllMatchResults.Item[]
    Else
        ' Match attempt failed
    End If
Catch ex As ArgumentException
    'Syntax error in the regular expression
End Try
```

In your case you are looking for the value from AllMatchResults.Count.

Using a great Regular Expression tool like [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) to build and test the expressions is a great help too. (The above code snippet was generated by RegexBuddy!)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Split](http://www.dotnetperls.com/split-vbnet) Function :

C#:

```
int count = txtContentofFile.Text.Split(desiredword).Length - 1;
```

VB.net:

```
Dim count As Integer = txtContentofFile.Text.Split(desiredword).Length - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim text As String = IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\file.txt")
Dim wordsToSearch() As String = New String() {"Hello", "World", "foo"}
Dim words As New List(Of String)()
Dim findings As Dictionary(Of String, List(Of Integer))

'Dividing into words
words.AddRange(text.Split(New String() {" ", Environment.NewLine()}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))

findings = SearchWords(words, wordsToSearch)
Console.WriteLine("Number of 'foo': " & findings("foo").Count)
```

Function used:

```
Private Function SearchWords(ByVal allWords As List(Of String), ByVal wordsToSearch() As String) As Dictionary(Of String, List(Of Integer))
    Dim dResult As New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of Integer))()
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    For Each s As String In wordsToSearch
        dResult.Add(s, New List(Of Integer))

        While i >= 0 AndAlso i < allWords.Count
            i = allWords.IndexOf(s, i)
            If i >= 0 Then dResult(s).Add(i)
            i += 1
        End While
    Next

    Return dResult
End Function
```

You will have not only the number of occurances, but the index positions in the file, grouped easily in a `Dictionary`.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer! I'm clearly a lot worse at vb.net than you so it'll take me a while to actually get something based off that working in my own roundabout code.

How do I take the answer from this and make it actually display in a textbox? txtnumberofdesired1.Text = dResult didn't work for me

Comment: @KieranO'mahony Thanks a lot. Take a look at the use at the first part, its a functional example. Basically, you call the function passing to it the words in where to look at, and the words that you are going to search, and it returns a Dictionary with the results of **each** word. The use is: `TextBox1.Text = dResult("myWord").Count`

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code

```
Function word_frequency(word_ As String, input As String) As Integer
    Dim ct = 0
    Try
        Dim wLEN = word_.Length
        Do While input.IndexOf(word_) <> -1
            Dim idx = input.IndexOf(word_) + wLEN
            ct += 1
            input = input.Substring(idx)
        Loop
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    Return ct
End Function
```

Comment: not useful without explanation as this is far from the only possible way.